# TextBox OnClick Event - What was clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, onclick

My problem is that i have a onClick on my TextBox, which sets the value to nothing. Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" OnClick="document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value = '';"></asp:TextBox>
```

So if the i click on the next TextBox there is no problem, but if i click in the panel the value is set to "", after just having typed the password and clicking.

Im allready using onFocus event of all my TextBoxes, to keep track of which element had last focus (cause im using ajax updatepanels).

**So my question is, is it possible to only fire the OnClick, if the click is in the TextBox?**

Edit:

Here is a link to the full code of my panel:
http://pastebin.com/Ujvy26wH

**Line: 22-35** is what im refering to with this question.

Comment: can you please post whole code with panel?

Comment: @ArunRana yes but it is probably a little confusing :)
http://pastebin.com/Ujvy26wH
It is from line 22 to 35 the textbox i want to set to "" when clicked is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is it possible to only fire the OnClick, if the
>   click is in the TextBox?

No, it's not possible. HTML Input text elements don't have onclick() events. You can fake them through other means. You have `blur()` or `onkeyup()`, to give you 2 examples, that you can use to perform certain actions on input text elements.